# looping over a xml list

Tags: r, xml, for-loop

I recently started working on xml files and I'm having a problem retrieving values from certain nodes.

I have a list of 64 xml files. Theese files are bills of a Hotel and are heavily nested.
I'm trying to loop over this list and getting the information over the "DatiBeniServizi" node. The problem is that this node is not the same for every bill and inside this node there's the "DettaglioLinee" node that has the informations I need to extract and put in a dataframe.

body is one of the two main nodes where informations I need are stored.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9UVo.png)

I've tried some codes but they don't work as I wanted to.

```
dati_beni_servizi <- vector("list", length(body))
for (i in seq_along(body)){
  dati_beni_servizi[[i]] <- unlist(body[[i]][[2]])
}  
df_dati_beni_seervizi <- bind_rows(dati_beni_servizi)
```

The code above just creates a dataframe with over 2000 columns with values spread over and lots of NAs.

Do you guys know a way to achieve what I'm asking? It would be very very helpfull!

Thanks in advance!

```
 <FatturaElettronicaHeader>
    <DatiTrasmissione>
      <IdTrasmittente>
        <IdPaese>IT</IdPaese>
        <IdCodice>00xxxxx</IdCodice>
      </IdTrasmittente>
      <ProgressivoInvio>219960</ProgressivoInvio>
      <FormatoTrasmissione>FPR12</FormatoTrasmissione>
      <CodiceDestinatario>xxxxxx</CodiceDestinatario>
      <PECDestinatario>xxxxxx@xxx.yyy.it</PECDestinatario>
    </DatiTrasmissione>
    <CedentePrestatore>
      <DatiAnagrafici>
        <IdFiscaleIVA>
          <IdPaese>IT</IdPaese>
          <IdCodice>000000000</IdCodice>
        </IdFiscaleIVA>
        <Anagrafica>
          <Denominazione>xxxxxxxx</Denominazione>
        </Anagrafica>
        <RegimeFiscale>RF01</RegimeFiscale>
      </DatiAnagrafici>
      <Sede>
        <Indirizzo>xxxxxxx</Indirizzo>
        <NumeroCivico>13</NumeroCivico>
        <CAP>xxxxxx</CAP>
        <Comune>xxxxx</Comune>
        <Provincia>PG</Provincia>
        <Nazione>IT</Nazione>
      </Sede>
      <IscrizioneREA>
        <Ufficio>PG</Ufficio>
        <NumeroREA>00000</NumeroREA>
        <CapitaleSociale>000000.00</CapitaleSociale>
        <StatoLiquidazione>LN</StatoLiquidazione>
      </IscrizioneREA>
      <Contatti>
        <Telefono>000000</Telefono>
        <Fax>00000000</Fax>
        <Email>xxxxx@yyyyyyy.it</Email>
      </Contatti>
    </CedentePrestatore>
    <CessionarioCommittente>
      <DatiAnagrafici>
        <IdFiscaleIVA>
          <IdPaese>IT</IdPaese>
          <IdCodice>000000000</IdCodice>
        </IdFiscaleIVA>
        <Anagrafica>
          <Denominazione>xxxxxxxx</Denominazione>
        </Anagrafica>
      </DatiAnagrafici>
      <Sede>
        <Indirizzo>xxxxxx</Indirizzo>
        <CAP>xxxxx</CAP>
        <Comune>xyz</Comune>
        <Provincia>PT</Provincia>
        <Nazione>IT</Nazione>
      </Sede>
    </CessionarioCommittente>
  </FatturaElettronicaHeader>
  <FatturaElettronicaBody>
    <DatiGenerali>
      <DatiGeneraliDocumento>
        <TipoDocumento>TD24</TipoDocumento>
        <Divisa>EUR</Divisa>
        <Data>2021-03-10</Data>
        <Numero>R21 013352</Numero>
        <ImportoTotaleDocumento>56.10</ImportoTotaleDocumento>
        <Causale>Assolve gli obblighi di cui all'art.62, comma 1 del d.legge 24/01/12 convertito, con modificazioni, dalla legge 24/03/12 n.27</Causale>
      </DatiGeneraliDocumento>
      <DatiDDT>
        <NumeroDDT>B21 014757</NumeroDDT>
        <DataDDT>2021-03-10</DataDDT>
      </DatiDDT>
    </DatiGenerali>
    <DatiBeniServizi>
      <DettaglioLinee>
        <NumeroLinea>1</NumeroLinea>
        <CodiceArticolo>
          <CodiceTipo>Nostro</CodiceTipo>
          <CodiceValore>21004</CodiceValore>
        </CodiceArticolo>
        <Descrizione>TORTELLINI ALLA CARNE *I L.P.*</Descrizione>
        <Quantita>6.000</Quantita>
        <UnitaMisura>KG</UnitaMisura>
        <PrezzoUnitario>3.480</PrezzoUnitario>
        <PrezzoTotale>20.88</PrezzoTotale>
        <AliquotaIVA>10.00</AliquotaIVA>
        <AltriDatiGestionali>
          <TipoDato>CF</TipoDato>
          <RiferimentoTesto>xxxxxxxxxxx</RiferimentoTesto>
        </AltriDatiGestionali>
        <AltriDatiGestionali>
          <TipoDato>PCONSEGNA</TipoDato>
          <RiferimentoTesto>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</RiferimentoTesto>
        </AltriDatiGestionali>
        <AltriDatiGestionali>
          <TipoDato>DP</TipoDato>
          <RiferimentoTesto>xxxxxxxx</RiferimentoTesto>
        </AltriDatiGestionali>
      </DettaglioLinee>
      <DettaglioLinee>
        <NumeroLinea>2</NumeroLinea>
        <CodiceArticolo>
          <CodiceTipo>Nostro</CodiceTipo>
          <CodiceValore>21006</CodiceValore>
        </CodiceArticolo>
        <Descrizione>RAVIOLI 1/2LUNA RICOTTA SPINACI *I L.P.*</Descrizione>
        <Quantita>6.000</Quantita>
        <UnitaMisura>KG</UnitaMisura>
        <PrezzoUnitario>3.100</PrezzoUnitario>
        <PrezzoTotale>18.60</PrezzoTotale>
        <AliquotaIVA>10.00</AliquotaIVA>
        <AltriDatiGestionali>
          <TipoDato>CF</TipoDato>
          <RiferimentoTesto>xxxxxxxx</RiferimentoTesto>
        </AltriDatiGestionali>
        <AltriDatiGestionali>
          <TipoDato>PCONSEGNA</TipoDato>
          <RiferimentoTesto>xxxxxxxxx</RiferimentoTesto>
        </AltriDatiGestionali>
        <AltriDatiGestionali>
          <TipoDato>DP</TipoDato>
          <RiferimentoTesto>xxxxxxx</RiferimentoTesto>
        </AltriDatiGestionali>
      </DettaglioLinee>
      <DettaglioLinee>
        <NumeroLinea>3</NumeroLinea>
        <CodiceArticolo>
          <CodiceTipo>Nostro</CodiceTipo>
          <CodiceValore>14018</CodiceValore>
        </CodiceArticolo>
        <Descrizione>CAROTINE PRIMIZIA                GR.2500</Descrizione>
        <Quantita>2.000</Quantita>
        <UnitaMisura>NR</UnitaMisura>
        <PrezzoUnitario>2.727</PrezzoUnitario>
        <PrezzoTotale>5.45</PrezzoTotale>
        <AliquotaIVA>04.00</AliquotaIVA>
        <AltriDatiGestionali>
          <TipoDato>CF</TipoDato>
          <RiferimentoTesto>xxxxxxxxx</RiferimentoTesto>
        </AltriDatiGestionali>
        <AltriDatiGestionali>
          <TipoDato>PCONSEGNA</TipoDato>
          <RiferimentoTesto>xxxxxxxxxx</RiferimentoTesto>
        </AltriDatiGestionali>
        <AltriDatiGestionali>
          <TipoDato>DP</TipoDato>
          <RiferimentoTesto>xxxxxxx</RiferimentoTesto>
        </AltriDatiGestionali>
      </DettaglioLinee>
      <DettaglioLinee>
        <NumeroLinea>4</NumeroLinea>
        <CodiceArticolo>
          <CodiceTipo>Nostro</CodiceTipo>
          <CodiceValore>14301</CodiceValore>
        </CodiceArticolo>
        <Descrizione>SPINACI FOGLIA FOGLIA 
 G.PANIERI)GR.2500</Descrizione>
        <Quantita>2.000</Quantita>
        <UnitaMisura>NR</UnitaMisura>
        <PrezzoUnitario>3.366</PrezzoUnitario>
        <PrezzoTotale>6.73</PrezzoTotale>
        <AliquotaIVA>04.00</AliquotaIVA>
        <AltriDatiGestionali>
          <TipoDato>CF</TipoDato>
          <RiferimentoTesto>xxxxxxxxxx</RiferimentoTesto>
        </AltriDatiGestionali>
        <AltriDatiGestionali>
          <TipoDato>PCONSEGNA</TipoDato>
          <RiferimentoTesto>xxxxxxxxxx</RiferimentoTesto>
        </AltriDatiGestionali>
        <AltriDatiGestionali>
          <TipoDato>DP</TipoDato>
          <RiferimentoTesto>xxxxxxxx</RiferimentoTesto>
        </AltriDatiGestionali>
      </DettaglioLinee>
      <DatiRiepilogo>
        <AliquotaIVA>10.00</AliquotaIVA>
        <ImponibileImporto>39.48</ImponibileImporto>
        <Imposta>3.95</Imposta>
      </DatiRiepilogo>
      <DatiRiepilogo>
        <AliquotaIVA>04.00</AliquotaIVA>
        <ImponibileImporto>12.18</ImponibileImporto>
        <Imposta>0.49</Imposta>
      </DatiRiepilogo>
    </DatiBeniServizi>
    <DatiPagamento>
      <CondizioniPagamento>TP02</CondizioniPagamento>
      <DettaglioPagamento>
        <ModalitaPagamento>MP01</ModalitaPagamento>
        <DataScadenzaPagamento>2021-04-08</DataScadenzaPagamento>
        <ImportoPagamento>56.10</ImportoPagamento>
        <IBAN>xxxxxxxxxxx</IBAN>
      </DettaglioPagamento>
    </DatiPagamento>
  </FatturaElettronicaBody>
</p:FatturaElettronica>
```

Comment: Please post a sample of XML file so we can understand structure. Your screenshot indicates a list of *parsed* XML content to R objects and not actual, original XML trees.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi @Parfait, unfortunately I cannot post all the xml trees since it contains sensible data, such as addresses, bank accounts and such. 
Maybe a part of the xml tree could be of help nontheless?
Thanks for the reply tho, appreciated :)

Comment: @Parfait ok I edited my post, is it a bit clearer now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider iterating through nodeset with `xml2` and then bind extracted nodes to data frame.

```r
library(xml2)
library(dplyr)

# LOAD XML
doc <- xml2::read_xml("Input.xml")

# RETRIEVE NODE SET
recs <- xml2::xml_find_all(doc, "//DettaglioLinee")

# ITERATE THROUGH NODE SET
df_list <- lapply(seq_along(recs), function(i) {
  ch_recs <- xml2::xml_find_all(
    doc, 
    # XPATH PARSES TWO SETS:
    paste0(
        "//DettaglioLinee[", i, "]/*[not(descendant::*)]|", # CHILDREN W/O DESCENDANTS
        "//DettaglioLinee[", i, "]/*/*")                    # GRANDCHILDREN
  )
  
  # BIND NODE NAMES AND TEXT TO DATA FRAME
  data.frame(rbind(setNames(
    c(xml2::xml_text(ch_recs)), 
    c(xml2::xml_name(ch_recs))
  ))) 
})

final_df <- dplyr::bind_rows(df_list)
```

**Output**

```
final_df
#   NumeroLinea CodiceTipo CodiceValore                                Descrizione Quantita UnitaMisura PrezzoUnitario PrezzoTotale AliquotaIVA TipoDato RiferimentoTesto TipoDato.1 RiferimentoTesto.1 TipoDato.2 RiferimentoTesto.2
# 1           1     Nostro        21004             TORTELLINI ALLA CARNE *I L.P.*    6.000          KG          3.480        20.88       10.00       CF      xxxxxxxxxxx  PCONSEGNA      xxxxxxxxxxxxx         DP           xxxxxxxx
# 2           2     Nostro        21006   RAVIOLI 1/2LUNA RICOTTA SPINACI *I L.P.*    6.000          KG          3.100        18.60       10.00       CF         xxxxxxxx  PCONSEGNA          xxxxxxxxx         DP            xxxxxxx
# 3           3     Nostro        14018   CAROTINE PRIMIZIA                GR.2500    2.000          NR          2.727         5.45       04.00       CF        xxxxxxxxx  PCONSEGNA         xxxxxxxxxx         DP            xxxxxxx
# 4           4     Nostro        14301 SPINACI FOGLIA FOGLIA \n G.PANIERI)GR.2500    2.000          NR          3.366         6.73       04.00       CF       xxxxxxxxxx  PCONSEGNA         xxxxxxxxxx         DP           xxxxxxxx
```

For all 64 XML files, wrap above in a function receiving XML file as input  to return `final_df` as output. Then, run another master `bind::rows` call:

```r
proc_xml <- function(xml_file) {
    doc <- read_xml(xml_file)
    ...
    return(final_df)
}

xml_files <- list.files(pattern=".xml")
final_df_list <- lapply(xml_files, proc_xml)

master_df <- dplyr::bind_rows(final_df_list)
```

Comment: Thank you very very much @Parfait, it worked like a charm! If  I may I would ask one last thing. 
Let's say I would like to create a new column into the master_df that shows to which of the 64 files of the xml list files it comes from.  For example, theese values come from the 4th files, theese from the first file and so on.
I would like to use this column as a key to bind all the other dataframes that contains values from the other nodes to create a final dataframe with all the information I need for further analysis.
Btw thank again for having helped me!

Comment: Great! Glad to help. To save a column of corresponding XML, just before `return(final_df)` assign a new column to input parameter: `final_df$source <- xml_file`

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively (and my preference) consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/), the special-purpose language designed to transform XML files. With R's `xslt` package (sister to `xml2`), you can run XSLT 1.0 scripts and even build a long-form data frame of the `<AltriDatiGestionali>` nodes:

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file, a special .xml file)*

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- PARSE DOWN TO REPEATED NODE -->
    <xsl:template match="/*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="FatturaElettronicaBody/descendant::AltriDatiGestionali"/>
     </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- PARSE PARENT AND GRANDPARENT NODES, AVOIDING REPETITION -->
    <xsl:template match="AltriDatiGestionali">
     <row>
       <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::DettaglioLinee/*[
                               name() != 'CodiceArticolo' 
                               and name() != 'AltriDatiGestionali'
                            ]  |
                            ancestor::DettaglioLinee/CodiceArticolo/*"/>
       <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
     </row>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93wniUN)</kbd>

**R**

```r
library(xml2)
library(xslt)

# LOAD XML AND XSLT
doc <- xml2::read_xml("Input.xml")
style <- xml2::read_xml("Style.xsl", package = "xslt")

# RUN TRANSFORMATION AND PARSE NODES
flat_xml <- xslt::xml_xslt(doc, style)
recs <- xml2::xml_find_all(flat_xml, "//row")

# BIND EACH CHILD TEXT AND NAME
df_list <- lapply(recs, function(r) {
  vals <- xml2::xml_children(r)
  
  data.frame(rbind(setNames(
      c(xml2::xml_text(vals)), 
      c(xml2::xml_name(vals))
  )))
})

final_df <- dplyr::bind_rows(df_list)

final_df
```

**Output**

```r
#    NumeroLinea CodiceTipo CodiceValore                                Descrizione Quantita UnitaMisura PrezzoUnitario PrezzoTotale AliquotaIVA  TipoDato RiferimentoTesto
# 1            1     Nostro        21004             TORTELLINI ALLA CARNE *I L.P.*    6.000          KG          3.480        20.88       10.00        CF      xxxxxxxxxxx
# 2            1     Nostro        21004             TORTELLINI ALLA CARNE *I L.P.*    6.000          KG          3.480        20.88       10.00 PCONSEGNA    xxxxxxxxxxxxx
# 3            1     Nostro        21004             TORTELLINI ALLA CARNE *I L.P.*    6.000          KG          3.480        20.88       10.00        DP         xxxxxxxx
# 4            2     Nostro        21006   RAVIOLI 1/2LUNA RICOTTA SPINACI *I L.P.*    6.000          KG          3.100        18.60       10.00        CF         xxxxxxxx
# 5            2     Nostro        21006   RAVIOLI 1/2LUNA RICOTTA SPINACI *I L.P.*    6.000          KG          3.100        18.60       10.00 PCONSEGNA        xxxxxxxxx
# 6            2     Nostro        21006   RAVIOLI 1/2LUNA RICOTTA SPINACI *I L.P.*    6.000          KG          3.100        18.60       10.00        DP          xxxxxxx
# 7            3     Nostro        14018   CAROTINE PRIMIZIA                GR.2500    2.000          NR          2.727         5.45       04.00        CF        xxxxxxxxx
# 8            3     Nostro        14018   CAROTINE PRIMIZIA                GR.2500    2.000          NR          2.727         5.45       04.00 PCONSEGNA       xxxxxxxxxx
# 9            3     Nostro        14018   CAROTINE PRIMIZIA                GR.2500    2.000          NR          2.727         5.45       04.00        DP          xxxxxxx
# 10           4     Nostro        14301 SPINACI FOGLIA FOGLIA \n G.PANIERI)GR.2500    2.000          NR          3.366         6.73       04.00        CF       xxxxxxxxxx
# 11           4     Nostro        14301 SPINACI FOGLIA FOGLIA \n G.PANIERI)GR.2500    2.000          NR          3.366         6.73       04.00 PCONSEGNA       xxxxxxxxxx
# 12           4     Nostro        14301 SPINACI FOGLIA FOGLIA \n G.PANIERI)GR.2500    2.000          NR          3.366         6.73       04.00        DP         xxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to say without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but perhaps this will solve your problem:

```r
results <- map(body, pluck, "DatiBeniServizi", "DettaglioLinee") %>% bind_cols()
```

Comment: Hi jared and thanks for replying. 
Unfortunately, your code just gives me the first values of the node DettaglioLinee of every single element of the xml files list and not all of them, since theese xml files can have more than one DettaglioLinee inside.

Comment: Oh - I understand - thanks for posting a sample of the XML - it's a lot clearer what you want to achieve